# ES6 computed property in react

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

My 4th caret is broken, I have no clue why it doesn't decrement.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.containerWidth = props.width || "100%";

  this.state = {
    current_hour: 0,
    current_minute: 0,
    hour_interval: 1,
    minute_interval: 1
  };

  // this.handleAdjuster = this.handleAdjuster.bind(this);
}

handleAdjuster(action, type) {
  if (action === "add") {
    this.setState({
      [`current_${type}`]: this.state[`current_${type}`] + this.state[`${type}_interval`]
    });
  } else if (action === "minus") {
    this.setState({
      [`current_${type}`]: this.state[`current_${type}`] - this.state[`${type}_interval`]
    });
  }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my click handler? I did a demo 
https://codesandbox.io/s/v8xw3lnzpy
to showcase my problem, try to click the 4th caret.

Comment: *"My 4th caret is broken"*??? Caret? As in diamonds? Or `^`? I don't see either in the code. Can you update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: *"Is there anything wrong with my click handler?"* Yes, you must use the callback version of `setState` any time you're creating new state based on existing state. [Details here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). It may not be the problem you're observing, but could well be a different problem if someone clicks fast enough.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder click the demo and you shall see it.

Comment: The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder why my increment work? I tried clicking fast I don't see any problem.

Comment: If it just happens that the updates don't get stacked, it'll work. But that doesn't mean it's right, or that you shouldn't do what the documentation says.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder will take note on that, but this question is about something else isn't? I don't think did not use the callback style caused the problem.

Comment: I suspect that's the case, yes, which is why I said that above. ("It may not be the problem you're observing...") I don't know for sure, because there isn't enough code in the question to know. The code in the question seems fine *other* than that issue, but I suspect the problem is in code you haven't shown.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, the codesandbox demo link has the working code with a reproducible problem

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri: Which isn't how SO works. [See this comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506148/es6-computed-property-in-react?noredirect=1#comment86016429_49506148) (and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506148/es6-computed-property-in-react?noredirect=1#comment86016338_49506148)).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I already reduce my app to small part of code to demo the problem, what's wrong with the question above?

Comment: I've already told you. Please see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506148/es6-computed-property-in-react?noredirect=1#comment86016338_49506148) and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506148/es6-computed-property-in-react?noredirect=1#comment86016429_49506148).

Comment: `Caret = ^`. `Carat = Precious stone measurement unit`. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @ArmanCharan: Quite right, my bad. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "minus" (4rth) carret is inside "add" (3rd) carret, and whenever you press "minus" first child is done and minus is done, but then also parent is done (and that is "add" 3rd carret) that overrides 4th carret. Put your 4rth carret div under your 3rd and not inside. Simple hierarchical mistake.

Something like this:

```
  <div>
    <div className="control-wrap">
      <div
        onClick={() => this.handleAdjuster("add", "minute")}
        className="caret-wrap"
      >
        <span className="caret">&#9650;</span>
      </div>

      <div
        onClick={() => this.handleAdjuster("minus", "minute")}
        className="caret-wrap"
      >
        <span className="caret">&#9660;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```